# Why does eval() give a SyntaxError on '='?

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

My Python 3 code:

```
test = "c.mode=0; c.preview=False"
eval(test)
```

Output:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    c.mode=0; c.preview=False
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why? It works fine at the REPL command prompt.

Comment: Because an assignment statement is not an expression. It cannot be `eval`uated.

Comment: @khelwood OK, how to I get Python to execute a statement represented in a string?

Comment: You need `exec` here

Comment: ...to `exec`ute a statement.